# Can I easily share a list of questions and answers I have answered myself?

Tags: discussion

Seeing as how we are now encouraged to ask and answer questions here, as if it were a blog; I would like to know if I can easily get a list of these to show to people.

For example, a benefit of a blog is that you can show potential employers your work experience and that you actually *can* write code.

Is there something like this?

Comment: Why not share your other answers too?

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but would prefer a "blog esq" format for showing off purposes to employers or potential clients.

Answer (score 2):

You can link to the Answers tab of your profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/699978/sergio-tapia?tab=answers

If you have a [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) profile, you can also showcase your best answers there.

Answer (score 1):

You can link to a query, e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A699978

Use `user:699978` to show only your posts. Also, there are many other options to narrow the search:

- Tag filter `[tag]`
- `is:question` or `is:answer`
- Minimum votes `votes:1`
- ...

For a complete list of all advanced search filters, [see this page](https://stackoverflow.com/search)